# Как запретить повторения значения в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, python-3.7

у меня есть база данных, она пополняется через скрипт на питоне.
[image: Скриншот из phpmyadmin]

В скрипте я использую такой код

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`nick`, `uid`, `money`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (nick, userid, money))
connection.commit()
```

Мне нужно чтобы если uid совпадал с имеющимся уже в базе данных, то просто выдавал ошибку. У меня появилась идея что запретить повторное использование значения можно сделать через базу данных, ведь если скрипт не сможет создать запись, то и так даст ошибку.

Comment: Ну Вы что не знаете как создавать ограничение уникальности или уникальные индексы в базе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо создать *Unique Constraint*, он может содержать одно поле или комбинация полей, которые определяют уникальную запись. Некоторые из полей могут содержать нулевые значения, если комбинация значений при этом остается уникальной ([статья](https://oracleplsql.ru/unique-constraints-mysql.html)).

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT uid_unique UNIQUE (uid);
```